# Html Importing with just standard Html, Can It Be Done?

Tags: html

Is there a way to import an html file in the same way you would a style sheet?
I just kinda want to be able to create a template of the main site without having to add or edit it every time I make an addition.

Comment: Not with html. Yes with server side code. Potentially with client-side code.

Comment: i recommend you look into the use of php. Also make a backup of a desired template !! :)